# Create download link with file from database and place it on a button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to make download button which take one file from database and download it. So far this is what I have and will appreciate some help.

My DownloadsController.php

```
class DownloadsController extends Controller
{
  public function download($file_name) {
    $file = DB::table('media')->where('status',1)->get();
    $file_path = public_path('files/'.$file);
    return response()->download($file_path);
  }
}
```

My route

```
Route::get('/files/{file}', 'DownloadsController@download');
```

The button

```
{!! Html::link('files/{file}', 'Download Media') !!}
```

What I see on the link is `http://example/files/{file}`. How to place the file on the download link?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically define your route in routes/web.php e.g.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#named-routes

```
Route::get('file/{file}', 'Controller@method')->name('file-download');
```

This means on your button you need to at the correct link for the filename e.g.

```
{!! Html::link('files/filename.jpg', 'Download Media') !!}
```

Remember this needs to be a valid filename. Alternartively you can use the route helper by inserting the route name as above followed by the parameter of the route e.g route('file-download', 'filename.jpg').

Final button link would look as follows using the routing helper;

```
{!! Html::link(route('file-download', 'filename.jpg'), 'Download Media') !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can I place dynamically the filename there? It will come from DB and I don't know what is the name

Comment: you'll need to fetch the file in question first from the database assign it to a variable. pass to your view and insert the $file->filename where I've put `filename.jpg`. If you need more help post  your controller and view file.

Comment: I've posted all in my question. This is the controler and the button in the view plus the route in web.php

Comment: Is the filename of the file in the media table?  Or is there a 'files' table?

Comment: It is in media table and the column is filename.

Comment: HTML <a> tag has a [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: Yes but I'm struggling with placing the file from database on the button.

Comment: It depends on your app. For example `asset(\Storage::url($model->path))` or from relation `asset(\Storage::url($model->relation->path))`

Comment: @LeventeOtta I'm not sure that I understand this